# convert REGCAN95 coordinates to OpenStreetMap coordinates (WGS84-Form in lat/long)

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, utm

I have some coordinates in datum REGCAN95, and I want to know how to convert them to something usable in OpenStreetMap.

I have found that REGCAN95 uses the EPSG codes as follows:

- 4082 REGCAN95 for UTM 27
- 4083 REGCAN95 for UTM 28

For example I have the  coordinate 28BR205306 or 28BR067530, which I want to find in OpenStreetMap or other webmaps. How can I convert them?

Comment: I would guess those are MGRS except they're missing one of the letters. I think they should be 28RBR, but that puts them offshore. At that precision they're only good to the closest 100 meters.

Comment: @mkennedy: Ok, but can you tell me how to interpret the numbers? Which is the x and which is the y coordinate? Just separate them in the middle? So three numbers for each coordinate? Or how can I enter them in one of the many transformation tools? And what does the R B R stand for? How did you guess the R is important or missing?

Comment: Please do a search for MGRS  here or Wikipedia. A comment isn't long enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from mkennedy I read the [Wikipedia article about MGRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system), which told me, that my coordinates, which are of the following form

```
4QFJ 123 678
```

represent a precision level of 100 m.

I then found the conversion tool [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/GeoConvert?input=&zone=-3&prec=0&option=Submit) at Sourceforge, which helped me convert the coordinates.